# Distributivity of wedge product over addition

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

The book I'm reading uses the definition of wedge product of n one-forms over $v_n$ vectors, by the determinant formula:

$$
d x_{i_1} \wedge d x_{i_2} \wedge \cdots \wedge d x_{i_n}\left(v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n\right)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{j=1}^n d x_{\sigma\left(i_j\right)}\left(v_j\right)
$$

With $a_1, a_2, b \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\omega_1=a_1 d x_{i_1} \wedge \cdots d x_{i_k}, \omega_2=a_2 d x_{j_1} \wedge \cdots d x_{j_k}$, and $\eta=b d x_{\ell}$. Use the formula above to show the distributivity property
$$
\left(\omega_1+\omega_2\right) \wedge \eta=\omega_1 \wedge \eta+\omega_2 \wedge \eta
$$

Every other book that I found just assumed this property is true or left as an exercise to the reader. I tried expanding $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ using the summation, though I got nowhere. How can I prove this?

Comment: This is a flaw in the book. From just that one definition, you cannot deduce the distributive property. How could you? If you know $dx\wedge dy(v_1,v_2)$ and  $dz\wedge dw(v_1,v_2)$, how do you get $(dx\wedge dy + dz\wedge dw)(v_1,v_2)$ without being told to add the results? How do you know $(a\,dx)(v_1) = a(dx(v_1))$? The text should have said to require linearity as well (i.e., scalar products and sums behave as you "think" they should).

Answer (score 1):

In that case, it is easier to write the exterior product as an antisymmetrized tensorial product, in order to avoid the reference to the exterior algebra basis, which tends to make the computations muddled.

Concretely, let $\omega_1,\omega_2 \in \Omega^k(V)$, $\eta \in \Omega^l(V)$ be $k$- and $l$-forms over space $V$ respectively and $v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l} \in V$ some vectors. Then we have :
$$
\begin{array}{l}
((\omega_1+\omega_2)\wedge\eta)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l}) \displaystyle \color{white}{\frac{1}{1}} \\
\begin{array}{rcl}
\color{white}{dd}
   &=& \displaystyle
   \mathrm{Alt}((\omega_1+\omega_2)\otimes\eta)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l}) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) ((\omega_1+\omega_2)\otimes\eta)(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) (\omega_1+\omega_2)(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)}) \cdot \eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \left\{\omega_1(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}) + \omega_2(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})\right\} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) (\omega_1\otimes\eta + \omega_2\otimes\eta)(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \mathrm{Alt}(\omega_1\otimes\eta + \omega_2\otimes\eta)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l}) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   (\omega_1\wedge\eta + \omega_2\wedge\eta)(v_1,\ldots,v_{k+l}) \color{white}{\frac{1}{1}}
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$
where we used only the definitions of the different objects.

Comment: Although your answer was great, the point of the exercise is to solve with the permutation! Antysymmetrized tensorial product will be covered later.

Comment: @VitorAquino That's basically the same, with a more messy notation : decompose for example $\omega_1(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})$ into $a_1\mathrm{d}x_1(v_{\sigma(1)}) \cdot \ldots \cdot \mathrm{d}x_k(v_{\sigma(k)})$ and recollect the terms. The main point of the demonstration doesn't rely on the antisymmetratization or permutation, but on the fact that the multiplication contained inside the tensorial product is distibutive over addition, since we work with a field.